# Why can't I consider inverse trigonometric functions as powers?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Given $$  \frac{d}{dx} \arcsin(x) = \frac {1}{ \sqrt{1 - x^2} } $$
and $$ \arcsin(x) = \sin^{-1}(x) $$  Why $ \frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(x) \neq \frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(x)$ ?

More precisely, $$ \frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(x) = -\sin(x)^{-2} \cdot \cos x = -\frac {\cos x} {\sin ^2 x}$$

- What did I not consider?
- How can I get to that?

Comment: Because $\arcsin(x)\ne (\sin(x))^{-1}$. The $-1$ in $\sin^{-1}$ is not a power in the multiplication sense, it is a power in the function composition sense.

Comment: This notation causes endless confusion for mathematics students.

Comment: By the way, the derivative of $\arcsin x$ is $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$, not $1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @JonathanHebert: You're wrong; the confusion *does* end. It ends when the students accept it as a fact and stop bothering about the details and semantics. Then by repeated usage, these notations become ingrained and suddenly feel normal within our vocabulary.

Comment: It's difference between $\sin^{-1}x$ and $(\sin x)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Nick: On the contrary, the student _should_ be concerned with the semantics of the notation -- especially here where he needs to choose between two _different_ semantics for it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Absolutely. My point was simply that there is no conceptual reason for the similarity in notations. Just like we accept that electric current is opposed to electron flow, we should accept this fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the notation $f^n(x)$ has two *different* meanings that are both in wide use for trigonometric functions.

$\sin^{-1}(x)$ always means the *inverse function* of $\sin$, never $1$ divided by the sine.

On the other hand $\sin^2(x)$ always means the *square* of the sine -- that is, the same thing as $(\sin x)^2$ -- never $\sin(\sin(x))$.

And similarly for the other trigonometric functions.

This is not logical or consistent, but it is too late to change it. You will just have to learn that this is how the notational convention works.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is too late to change it. If we embrace $\arcsin$ and $\sin(x)^2$ over the more confusing forms, then over time we will see change.

Comment: @Regret: Anyone can do that if they choose, but that will not stop _others_ from using the traditional notation, so in order to be able to communicate one has to learn that too.

Comment: @Regret: `*shrug*` I'm using it. It is not really "illogical", merely ambiguous, and doesn't seem to create any serious problem in practice. Both uses are special cases of good useful notations that we don't have any good alternative to.

Comment: @Henning: I'd say $\sin(x)^2$ is just as easy to write as $\sin^2(x)$, but less ambiguous. Perhaps $\sin^2$ is better if you drop the parentheses from around the argument, but then you're also using another somewhat ambiguous notation.

Comment: @Regret: $\sin^2$ is necessary when you're not supplying an argument -- e.g. if you're working in a function algebra.

Comment: @Henning: I do recall using $\sin^2$ myself when referring to just the function. Apologies if my comments here came off as argumentative. I agree the notations do have their uses, although perhaps others work better in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^{-1}(x)$ is not the same thing as $\sin(x)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}$. It's not exponentiating, it's taking the inverse, which is just $\arcsin$.